# Mutt config: # of characters displayed

Tags: mutt, sms

I use mutt for my Gmail (IMAP).  I respond to a lot of messages that are TXT messages from cell phones.  When I reply to them I would like to know how many characters I have typed so I can avoid sending multi-page SMS.

An on-screen display of total characters (must include spaces) or a keyboard combination would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mutt uses an external editor, so how you do this depends on the editor you've chosen. If you're using Vim, typing the two-character sequence `g Ctrl-G` will show you a line of buffer statistics at the bottom of the screen, including the total number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

What editor are you using in mutt? For example, I'm using `nano` (my `/usr/bin/editor` is symlinked to `/etc/alternatives/editor` which is symlinked to `/bin/nano` - a similar effect is obtained if `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` is set to `/bin/nano`).

If you start `nano` with `-c` (or `--const`) or have `set const` in your `~/.nanorc` it will display the character count at the bottom of the screen as you type.